# OpenMP not working with my Visual studio?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

/*
This source code can be downloaded from supercomputingblog.com
The purpose of this code is to ensure that OpenMP is working and running on multiple threads.
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // This statement should only print once
    printf("Starting Program!\n");

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        // This statement will run on each thread.
        // If there are 4 threads, this will execute 4 times in total
        printf("Running on multiple threads\n");
    }

    // We're out of the parallelized secion.
    // Therefor, this should execute only once
    printf("Finished!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

After being frustrated with my previous attempts of using openmp and it only running on one thread I decided to test it using the code above.

The expected output should print  “Running on multiple threads” multiple times based on the number of threads being used (I have also tried specifying #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)) but it still only prints once.

Under properties -> C/C++ -> Language Open MP is enabled.
Conformance mode is set to **No**.

**Additional information**

- I am building my project then using cmd to run it via test (ConsoleApplication1 test)
- My Visual studio: VS2017 Community 15.9.14
- My processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i&-4860HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: You need to enable OpenMP with the `/openmp` command line option

Comment: I compile using batch build and /openmp is in the command line option

Comment: What happens if you run it from inside VS? It works with VS2019.

Comment: So if I run it from within the Local windows debugger it works as intended. When I try to run it from the cmd it only runs on one thread

Comment: Make sure you are not running a different executable file. Also, a side node - OpenMP support in VS is deprecated. The compiler supports only version 2.0 of the specification and the current one is 5.0. You need a different compiler if you are to learn OpenMP on Windows - either Intel C/C++ or Clang.